# Adding noise vector in a signal vector using matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have two vectors. One is of noise and one is of my signal. If I want to add noise vector to signal vector how can i do it. My noise dimension is 41001x1 and my signal is 88200x1.

Comment: Why not add a random vector of the same size as the signal ? Also you should provide a minimal and reproducible example, check: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I cant. I am suppose to only add these two vectors

Comment: Then you need to explain how it should be done ! Matlab can not sum two vectors of different length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to product a signal and noise of the dimensions you mentioned:

```
time = (1:88200)';
sig = sin(0.005 * time);
noise = 0.1 * randn(41001, 1);
```

Since you cannot add two vectors of the same length, I chose to replicate the noise signal by repeating it so that it is the same length as `sig`:

```
multiplier = ceil(length(sig) / length(noise));
noise = repmat(noise, multiplier, 1);
noise = noise(1:length(sig));
```

Now the `noise` and `sig` are the same length they can be added and plotted together

```
plot(time, noise + sig)
```

In this answer, I'm assuming that `noise` and `sig` have the same sample rate, but `noise` is just too short for some reason. If the noise signal is at a different sample rate, then you would want to use `interp1` or resample to get the same sample rate and number of points.